# Instead of passing numbers in the struct, we first need to pass processes and resources. For e.g P1,P2,P3,R1,R2

Tags: c, list, graph, deadlock, depth-first-search

Can you please modify my code to be able to fulfill the following requirements:

-Instead of passing numbers in the struct, we first need to pass processes and resources. For e.g P1,P2,P3,R1,R2...

-Then the pointer should be as such: PA->RS, PB->RT, PC->RS, PD->RS, PD->RT, PE->RV, PF->RS, PG->RU, RG->PA, RU->PD, RT->PE, RW->PF, RV->PG

-Our program should find a cycle by considering the adjency list. If 2 nodes are repeated in the adjency list, it means that there is a cycle and hence the system is deadlocked and a message should be outputted. For now, i just want to hardcode the above processes and resources to see how it works.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

// Define maximum number of vertices in the graph
#define N 10

// Data structure to store graph
struct Graph {
   // An array of pointers to Node to represent adjacency list
   struct Node* head[N];
};

// A data structure to store adjacency list nodes of the graph
struct Node {
   int dest;
   struct Node* next;
};

// data structure to store graph edges

struct Edge {
   int src, dest;
};

// Function to create an adjacency list from specified edges

struct Graph* createGraph(struct Edge edges[], int n)
{
   unsigned i;


   // allocate memory for graph data structure

   struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));

   // initialize head pointer for all vertices

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       graph->head[i] = NULL;

   // add edges to the directed graph one by one

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       // get source and destination vertex

       int src = edges[i].src;
       int dest = edges[i].dest;

       // allocate new node of Adjacency List from src to dest

       struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
       newNode->dest = dest;

       // point new node to current head

       newNode->next = graph->head[src];

       // point head pointer to new node

       graph->head[src] = newNode;
   }

   return graph;
}

// Function to print adjacency list representation of graph

void printGraph(struct Graph* graph){
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {

// print current vertex and all ts neighbors

       struct Node* ptr = graph->head[i];
       while (ptr != NULL)
       {
           printf("(%d -> %d)\t", i, ptr->dest);
           ptr = ptr->next;
       }

       printf("\n");
   }
}

// Directed Graph Implementation in C

int main(void)
{
   // input array containing edges of the graph (as per above diagram)
   // (x, y) pair in the array represents an edge from x to y


   struct Edge edges[] =
   {
       { 1, 2 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 1 },
       { 1, 1 }, { 3, 1 }, { 5, 1 }, { 6, 2 },
       { 4, 4 }
   };

   // calculate number of edges

   int n = sizeof(edges)/sizeof(edges[0]);

   // construct graph from given edges

   struct Graph *graph = createGraph(edges, n);

   // print adjacency list representation of graph

   printGraph(graph);

   return 0;
}

-
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "Can you please modify my code to be able to fulfill the following requirements" of course.  Given the state of the requirements list however, I'll be charging a premium over my usual hourly rate.  I'd estimate an hour or two to nail down the specs, then we can talk about estimating the rest of the work.  Deal?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Also, for homework assignments, we expect to see the full text of the assignment, as your professor wrote it, not paraphrased.